# How to make typesafe-actions work with redux-logic transform?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-logic, typesafe-actions

Redux-logic provides a method called transform, which allows actions to be transformed before they reach the reducers. This is helpful for various situations. Typically I want to dispatch an action which has only my user input, and sometimes my reducer will need supporting data in order to perform the state update.

So, I can do this in a redux-logic transform process, but this seems to conflict with typesafe-actions (which I'm also using). How can I tell typescript that my actions are getting transformed before they reach the reducer?

Imagine I dispatch with a payload like `{ userName: string }` but my transform process adds a property so I get `{ userName: 'John Doe', recordId: 9 }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to typescript, but realized that I know how to solve this.

In the reducer we normally import the action types, it goes like this:

```
// actions.ts
import { action } from 'typesafe-actions';
import actionTypes from './actionTypes';

export const someAction = (data) = action(
  actionTypes.SOME_ACTION_TYPE,
  { data },
);

// reducer.ts
import { ActionType } from 'typesafe-actions';
import { StateSlice } from './types';
import * as actions from './actions';

const initialState: StateSlice = { ... };

const reducer = (state = initialState, action: ActionType<typeof actions>): StateSlice => {
  ...
};
```

So to update this to accept actions which have been modified by a redux-logic middleware, we have to tell typescript that the type has been extended. It goes like this:

```
// actions.ts
import { action } from 'typesafe-actions';
import actionTypes from './actionTypes';

export const someAction = (data) = action(
  actionTypes.SOME_ACTION_TYPE,
  { data },
);

// reducer.ts
import { ActionType } from 'typesafe-actions';
import { StateSlice, SOME_TYPE } from './types';
import * as actions from './actions';

type OriginalAction = ActionType<typeof actions.someAction>;
interface MutatedAction1 extends OriginalAction {
  payload: OriginalAction['payload'] & {
    thingWeAddedInReduxLogic: SOME_TYPE;
  };
}

// repeat for other actions, then use a union type like this

type MutatedActionType = MutatedAction1 | MutatedAction2 | ... ;

const initialState: StateSlice = { ... };

const reducer = (state = initialState, action: MutatedActionType): StateSlice => {
  ...
};
```

This is an abbreviated version of the real code that I was able to make work. Hope this helped someone.

Answer (score 0):

there is a package about standard action type
https://github.com/redux-utilities/flux-standard-action

and redux-logic provide https://github.com/jeffbski/redux-logic/blob/master/definitions/action.d.ts which is action interface we need to use